# What does the !! operator do?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what does the '!!' operator do?
Is it a NOT NOT statement?

For example:

```
someFunc(foo) {
    return !! foo;
}
// Return foo only if foo exists?
```

Comment: It's not an operator itself, it's two `!` operators in a row. In this case it uses javascripts type coersion to turn whatever foo is into a boolean.

Comment: Exact duplicate, actually.

Comment: My apologies for the duplicate.  I did search for this prior to posting but didn't get any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this is not an operator.converts  it to boolean in javascript

EXAMPLE:

```
var test = true;

!test = false; //It will converted to false
!!test = true; //Again it will converted to true
```

Answer (score 2):

`!` is the "not" operator, casting its one argument to a boolean and negating it.

The second `!` negates it back, so effectively `!!` casts the value to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Converts foo to boolean.

```
var foo = "TEST";

!foo // Result: false
!!foo // Result: true
```